# Bazel test with expect_failure = True and "bazel cquery //..." failure

Tags: testing, bazel

I use Bazel and bazel_skylib for test. There are a few targets that should fail and I test it with `expect_failure = True` and all work correctly.
Also, the target that fails is marked `tags=["manual"]` and does not participate in the build of all targets.
But, for some reason, I have to use command: bazel cquery //... and obviously an error occurs.

Is there a way to avoid this? I need both tests and cquery to work without errors

```
#BUILD
load(":test_rules.bzl", "fail_rule", "fail_test")

fail_rule(
    name = "fail_target",
    tags = ["manual"]
)

fail_test(
    name = "test_fail_target",
    target_under_test = ":fail_target",
)
```

```
#test_rules.bzl
load("@bazel_skylib//lib:unittest.bzl", "analysistest", "asserts")

def _fail_test_impl(ctx):
    env = analysistest.begin(ctx)
    target_under_test = env.ctx.attr.target_under_test[0]
    asserts.expect_failure(env, "always fail")
    return analysistest.end(env)

fail_test = analysistest.make(
    _fail_test_impl,
    expect_failure = True,
)

def _impl(ctx):
    fail("always fail")

fail_rule = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
)
```

**bazel build - OK**

```
:~/PycharmProjects/bazel_project$ bazel build //test:all
INFO: Analyzed target //test:test_fail_target (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //test:test_fail_target up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/test/test_fail_target.sh
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.093s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
```

**bazel test - OK**

```
:~/PycharmProjects/bazel_project$ bazel test //test:all
INFO: Analyzed target //test:test_fail_target (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
Target //test:test_fail_target up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/test/test_fail_target.sh
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.079s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
//test:test_fail_target                                         (cached) PASSED in 0.1s
```

**bazel cquery //... - error as expected, this is what I want to avoid**

```
:~/PycharmProjects/bazel_project$ bazel cquery //...
ERROR: /Users/***/PycharmProjects/bazel_project/test/BUILD:3:10: in fail_rule rule //test:fail_target: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/***/PycharmProjects/bazel_project/test/test_rules.bzl", line 15, column 9, in _impl
                fail("always fail")
Error in fail: always fail
ERROR: /Users/***/PycharmProjects/bazel_project/test/BUILD:3:10: Analysis of target '//test:fail_target' failed
ERROR: Analysis of target '//test:fail_target' failed; build aborted: 
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.068s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```